# how to change the for loop in the code to a while loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop

I am setting up a chatbot program. Can you please tell me how to change 
the for loop in the code to a while loop in the code.

I Have tried:

```
int j = 0;
while(j<numinputs()){
...
j++;
}

...

String[] inputs;
inputs = new String[numinputs];
int i = 0;
while (i < numinputs) {
    inputs[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter key word " + (i + 1) + " ");
    if (inputs[i].contains("?") || inputs[i].isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Response");
    } else
        i = i + 1;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputs));
for (int j = 0; j < numinputs; j++) {
    String search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tell me more about" + " " + inputs[j]);
    System.out.println(search);
    if (search.contains("exit")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

Here is the code I am trying to change:

```
inputs = new String[numinputs];
int i = 0;
while (i < numinputs) {
    inputs[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputs));
for (int j = 0; j < numinputs; j++) {
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us an intact and functioning `for` loop.

Comment: I have added the functioning for loop

Answer (score 2):

We can try the following logic:

```
int j = 0;
while (j < numinputs) {
    String search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tell me more about" + " " + inputs[j]);
    System.out.println(search);
    if (search.contains("exit")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    ++j;
}
```

The above loop should be logically identical to the `for` loop you currently have.  The difference is that the dummy variable loop counter `j` is defined outside the `while` loop, and also the increment step happens as a separate line within the loop.

Comment: Thanks Tim I have tried this however:   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputs));
      int j = 0;
      while (j<numinputs){
      j++;
  }
      String search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tell me more about" + " " + inputs[j]);
   System.out.println(search);
   if (search.contains("exit")) {
    System.exit(0);
   }
  }

}

Comment: I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
 at ChatBot1.main(ChatBot1.java:26)

Answer (score 0):

fallow this

```
    int j = 0;
    while (j < numinputs) {
      String search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tell me more about" + " " + inputs[j]);
      System.out.println(search);
      if (search.contains("exit")) {
      System.exit(0);
      }
      ++j;
   }
```

For loop and while both are same ...

In for loop all three arguments(initialization;decision;inc/dec) are in same line
But in While loop you have to split all three arguments.

But logically for&while are same..

Hope it will help you ..

keep learn

[You can find best diffrences through this link](https://java.meritcampus.com/core-java-topics/for-vs-while-loop-in-java)

Comment: Thank you @Sivareddy for you help, However I have encountered an other error of: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2 at ChatBot1.main(ChatBot1.java:25)